# How does one install an extension for Chrome browser from the local file system?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How does one install an extension for Chrome browser from the local file system?

Answer (score 71):

Found a [set of instructions](http://www.blackweb20.com/2010/01/11/creating-your-own-google-chrome-extension/) online for loading your own custom extension:

> - Navigate to `chrome://extensions`
> - Expand the Developer dropdown menu and click “Load Unpacked Extension”
> - Navigate to the local folder containing the extension’s code and click Ok
> - Assuming there are no errors, the extension should load into your browser

Comment: Ok, updated the answer to include the correct way to upload extensions into your browser. I tested it on my own and it worked.

Comment: Here is the link from where I got those instructions. http://www.blackweb20.com/2010/01/11/creating-your-own-google-chrome-extension/

Comment: If this worked for you, please mark it as an answer! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Gots to click the "Developer" check box nowadays, too

Comment: **Note** Your unpacked extension is somewhat „hot linked“ to its original place. It is NOT copied to the profile folder, changes e.g. on styles still have direct effect. That is GOOD for a developer (instant feedback on changes, little “deployment” hassle), this is BAD if you then remove the extension folder (believing, it got copied into the profile folder... Nope, it didn't.)

Answer (score 30):

What kind of extension is it? Is it a .CRX file? A (possibly ZIP’d) folder? A .JS user-script? The process differs for each.

- **CRX:**

  1. Drag and drop the .CRX file onto the page `chrome://extensions`
  2. Click the *Install* button in the prompt at the bottom of the screen
- **Folder:**

  1. If it is ZIP’d, extract the contents somewhere
  2. In Chrome, open `chrome://extensions/`
  3. Click + *Developer mode*
  4. Click *Load unpacked extension…*
  5. Navigate to the extension’s folder and click OK
  6. Delete the (extracted) folder (the extension was copied)
- **User Script:**

  1. Exit Chrome (all windows)
  2. Copy the .JS file to the `User Scripts` folder in your [`User Data`](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory) folder
  3. Run Chrome

Comment: Chrome doesn't by default allow you to install custom .crx extensions anymore. There must be an option for this, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @agnoster, you can still use extensions from other than the webstore, but you *must* drop it into `chrome://extensions` now.

Comment: @Synetech - Is this still a valid way? Can I use this to migrate extensions not available on App Store to new PC?

Comment: Very nice @Synetech! That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

To install a user script, the file must have a suffix of `.user`, like `my_script.user.js`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `chrome://extensions/`
2. Toggle the "Developer mode" switch on
3. Drag and drop the ZIP or CRX file or the folder to the browser window.