# How to force the installation of a local extension with a Chrome policy?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I use the Google Chrome policies on a couple of Linux workstations to force some settings. I need to force each browser to have a local extension (not from the Google Chrome store).

`ExtensionInstallForcelist` can be used to force the installation of public extensions, but It does not seem to work for private local extensions. Can it actually be used for those extensions?

Comment: Have you tried : https://superuser.com/questions/247651/how-does-one-install-an-extension-for-chrome-browser-from-the-local-file-system

Comment: This is for the manual installation on your own browser. I'm looking to automate it on several workstations with Chrome policies.